# Qt Key Pressevent Enter

Tags: qt, keypress, qkeyevent

```
void LoginModle::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << event->key() << "\t" << Qt::Key_Enter << "\t" << QKeyEvent::Enter;
    if( event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter)
        OKButtonClicked();
    else
        QDialog::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

This code is very simple, class `LoginModle` inherits from `QWidget`. run this code and when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it shows:

```
16777220     16777221    10
```

It means that my <kbd>Enter</kbd> in keyboard is `16777220`, but in Qt, it was defined as `16777221`.

My system is Elementary OS (Freya), which is based on Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there something wrong with my driver or just the program's mistake ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

16777220(dec) = 1000004(hex), so according to [this list](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum), pressed key is "Return". Look at the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key) - Enter key is in numeric keypad, key used by you is called in Qt "Return key".

Comment: but, I think that 16777220 is a dec. number, 1000004 is a hex. number.;)

Answer (score 17):

The Enter key referred to by `Qt::Key_Enter` is the Enter key on the numeric keypad. You are pressing the "Enter" key that's next to the letters on your keyboard. That's known as the Return key, and its value is represented by `Qt::Key_Return`, which equals 16777220.

So, in order to support both key presses, you would modify the if statement as follows:

```
if( (event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter) || (event->key() == Qt::Key_Return))
        OKButtonClicked();
    else
        QDialog::keyPressEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just the problem of `carriage return`(CR) and `line feed`(LF). CR is encoded as 13 (0D in hexadecimal), denoted by '\r' in C and C++; and LF is encoded as 10 (0A in hexadecimal), denoted by '\n' in C and C++. `Qt::Key_Enter` stands for CR, while `Qt::Key_Return` stands for LF. When you press `Enter` key on the keyboard, the program may receive LF in fact, rather than CR. You can test by the `getchar()` function - you press the `Enter` key, but it returns 10. As a result, you should read the `Qt::Key_Return` event, rather than the `Qt::Key_Enter` event.

If you **really, really** care about the reason, please check the history of the [typewriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter), because CR and LF stand for two **different** operations in the typewriter.